# How can I show radius of this circle exactly?

Tags: calculations

I want to show radius of this circle. The correct result of radius is `7/sqrt(3)`. My code.

```
\documentclass[border = 1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,backgrounds,fpu} 
\newcommand{\PgfmathsetmacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join = round, line cap = round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{7} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{8} 
    \PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myr}{{sqrt(-
     pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)* pow(\c,2)/ (pow(\a,4)  + pow(\b,4)  + pow(\c,4)- 2
     *pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)  - 2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\b,2)-2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\a,2) ))}}

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\c,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at  ({(pow(\b,2) + pow(\c,2) - pow(\a,2))/(2*\c)},{sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c) *(-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))/(2*\c)},0);
    \coordinate (T) at  (\c/2, {\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c)))},0);
    \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/right,T/below}
    {
        \fill (\point) circle (1.8pt);
        \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
    }
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (\myr); 
    \end{scope}
 \pgfmathparse{\myr}
 \pgfmathresult
\end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

I tried

```
\pgfmathparse{\myr}
 \pgfmathresult
```

I can't obtain the result. How can I get the result automatically (not by hand)?

Comment: E.g. `\draw (T)  -- (C) node[midway,sloped,fill=white] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\myr}$cm};`.

Comment: @Dunno This is an approximate result. Can I get exactly result?

Comment: `\pgfmathparse{\myr}
 \xdef\r{\pgfmathresult} $\r{} cm$`

Comment: @koleygr The approximate about `4.0414518843273803516`. I want to exactly result.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 ... do you mean the actual real number of `\frac{7}{3}\cdot\sqrt{3}` ... Sorry if I didn't understood, but this is a number of infinitive digits ... Please make it more clear (may be my English is the problem.)... But do you expect a number like above in this format... or with more digits?

Comment: @koleygr Yes. `\frac{7}{3}\cdot\sqrt{3}`.

Comment: Ok... I am afraid that `pgf` uses the approximations to make its calculations...

Comment: Look on `Sage` and `sagetex` allow symbolic calculations to be made.http://www.sagemath.org/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is only very limited support for fraction detection and so on in pgf, and as soon as square roots are involved I think you do need to do some of the things by hand. (To be fair, computer algebra systems are also not great at detecting such expressions, but if you use those to parse the expressions then you can get exact result. Yet LaTeX is not such a computer algebra system.) You can use the keys

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,frac, frac denom=3,frac whole=false}
```

to obtain

```
\documentclass[border = 1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,backgrounds,fpu} 
\newcommand{\PgfmathsetmacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join = round, line cap = round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{7} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{8} 
    \PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myr}{{sqrt(-
     pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)* pow(\c,2)/ (pow(\a,4)  + pow(\b,4)  + pow(\c,4)- 2
     *pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)  - 2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\b,2)-2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\a,2) ))}}

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\c,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at  ({(pow(\b,2) + pow(\c,2) - pow(\a,2))/(2*\c)},{sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c) *(-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))/(2*\c)},0);
    \coordinate (T) at  (\c/2, {\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c)))},0);
    \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/right,T/below}
    {
        \fill (\point) circle (1.8pt);
        \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
    }
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (\myr); 
    \end{scope}
 \draw (T)  -- (C) node[midway,sloped,fill=white] {%
 \pgfmathparse{\myr/sqrt(3)}%
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,frac, frac denom=3,frac whole=false}%  
 $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\cdot\sqrt{3}\,$cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one can do better than that but to the best of my knowledge the routines for doing the required integer arithmetic are not yet implemented in `pgf` (and there is a slight chance that there is no real package for those). The main obstacle is that `gcd`, which is very useful to cancel common factors in fractions, does not yet work with `fpu`. On the other hand, you need `fpu` here because the numbers are so large. So I added variant of `gcd` (called `gcdFPU`) and a number of other routines such as `integerpower` which allows one to determine the power of a factor in an integer. For instance, `integerpower(12,2)` yields `2` since `12=2^2 times something that is not divisible by 2`. This can be used to pull squares out of the square root.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu} 
\newcounter{ifactor}
\newcommand{\PgfmathsetmacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\newcommand{\PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{#1}{round(#2)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
% the following functions are based on 
% * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177109 (digitcount,digitsum,lastdigit)
% * https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501895 (memberQ)
% or new in the sense that they were developed on the basis of the existing
% pgf functions
\makeatletter
\newcount\c@Digits
\newcount\c@Powers
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{digitcount}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
  \global\c@Digits=0
  \expandafter\DigitCount@i#1\@nil%
  \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
% \def\GroupDigits#1{%
%   \global\c@Digits=0
%   \expandafter\DigitCount@i#1\@nil%
%   \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}}
\def\DigitCount@i#1#2\@nil{%
  \advance\c@Digits by \@ne
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\DigitCount@i#2\@nil\fi
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{digitsum}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
  \global\c@Digits=0
  \expandafter\DigitSum@i#1\@nil%
  \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
% \def\DigitSum#1{%
%   \global\c@Digits=0
%   \expandafter\DigitSum@i#1\@nil%
%   \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}}
\def\DigitSum@i#1#2\@nil{%
  \advance\c@Digits by #1
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\DigitSum@i#2\@nil\fi
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lastdigit}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
    \global\c@Digits=0
    \expandafter\LastDigit@i#1\@nil%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
% \def\LastDigit#1{%
%   \global\c@Digits=0
%   \expandafter\LastDigit@i#1\@nil%
%   \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}}
\def\LastDigit@i#1#2\@nil{%
  \c@Digits=#1
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\LastDigit@i#2\@nil\fi
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{integerpower}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
    \global\c@Powers=0%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pgfutil@tmpa}{#1}%
    \loop\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{gcd(\pgfutil@tmpa,#2)}%0
    \ifnum\itest>1\relax%
    \advance\c@Powers by \@ne%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pgfutil@tmpa}{\pgfutil@tmpa/#2}%
    \repeat%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Powers)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{integerpower2}{1}{% works with large numbers
  \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \global\c@Powers=0%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{#1}%
    \loop%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pgfutil@tmpb}{lastdigit(\pgfutil@tmpa)}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{iseven(\pgfutil@tmpb)}%
    \ifnum\itest=1%
    \advance\c@Powers by \@ne%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{\pgfutil@tmpa/2}%
    \repeat%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Powers)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{integerpower3}{1}{% works with large numbers
  \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \global\c@Powers=0%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{#1}%
    \loop%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{divby3(\pgfutil@tmpa)}%
    \ifnum\itest=1%
    \advance\c@Powers by \@ne%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{\pgfutil@tmpa/3}%
    \repeat%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Powers)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup} 
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{memberQ}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{0}%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{#2}%
    \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i\pgfutil@firstofone#1\pgfmath@token@stop
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpb}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup}
\def\pgfmath@member@i#1{%
    \ifx\pgfmath@token@stop#1%
    \else
      \ifnum#1=\pgfutil@tmpa\relax%
      \gdef\pgfutil@tmpb{1}%
      \fi%
      \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i
    \fi} 
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{isevenFPU}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{iseven(lastdigit(#1))}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{isoddFPU}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{isodd(lastdigit(#1))}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}        
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{divby3}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{memberQ({3,6,9},digitsum(digitsum(#1)))}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}   
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gcdFPU}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \pgfmathcontinuelooptrue
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{#1}%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpb}{#2}%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(\pgfutil@tmpa==0,1,0)}%
    \ifnum\itest=1\relax
      \pgfmathcontinueloopfalse
      \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{\pgfutil@tmpb}%
    \fi%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(\pgfutil@tmpb==0,1,0)}%
    \ifnum\itest=1\relax
      \pgfmathcontinueloopfalse
      \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpb}{\pgfutil@tmpa}%
    \fi%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{abs(\pgfutil@tmpa)}%
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpb}{abs(\pgfutil@tmpb)}%
    \loop
      \ifpgfmathcontinueloop%
      \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(\pgfutil@tmpa==\pgfutil@tmpb,1,0)}%
      \ifnum\itest=1\relax
        \pgfmathcontinueloopfalse
      \else
        \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\itest}{ifthenelse(\pgfutil@tmpa>\pgfutil@tmpb,1,0)}%
        \ifnum\itest=1\relax
          \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpa}{\pgfutil@tmpa-\pgfutil@tmpb}%
        \else
          \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\pgfutil@tmpb}{\pgfutil@tmpb-\pgfutil@tmpa}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \repeat
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpa}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{factorinteger}{1}{%
\begingroup% not yet done
\endgroup
}  
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Pgfmathfraction}[3]{\begingroup%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynumerator}{#2/gcd(#2,#3)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydenominator}{#3/gcd(#2,#3)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\foreach \a/\b/\c in {3/4/5,6/7/8,5/7/8}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join = round, line cap = round,
declare function={numerator(\a,\b,\c)=pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)* pow(\c,2);
denominator(\a,\b,\c)=-pow(\a,4)  - pow(\b,4)  - pow(\c,4)+% 
2*pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)+2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\b,2)+2*pow(\c,2)*pow(\a,2);}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=elli]
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mynumerator}{numerator(\a,\b,\c)}
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mydenominator}{denominator(\a,\b,\c)}
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mygcd}{gcdFPU(\mynumerator,\mydenominator)}
    \message{numerator=\mynumerator,denominator=\mydenominator,gcd=\mygcd^^J}
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\newnumerator}{\mynumerator/\mygcd}
    \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\newdenominator}{\mydenominator/\mygcd}
    \message{new numerator=\newnumerator,new denominator=\newdenominator^^J}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myprenum}{1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mypreden}{1}
    \foreach \Prime in {2,3,5,7,11,13,17}
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{integerpower(\newnumerator,\Prime)}
     \ifnum\myint>1
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{2*int(\myint/2)}
      \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\newnumerator}{\newnumerator/pow(\Prime,\myint)}
      \xdef\newnumerator{\newnumerator}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myprenum}{\myprenum*pow(\Prime,\myint/2)}
      \xdef\myprenum{\myprenum}
     \fi
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{integerpower(\newdenominator,\Prime)}
     \ifnum\myint>0
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{2*int(\myint/2)}
      \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\newdenominator}{\newdenominator/pow(\Prime,\myint)}
      \xdef\newdenominator{\newdenominator}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mypreden}{\mypreden*pow(\Prime,\myint/2)}
      \xdef\mypreden{\mypreden}
     \fi
    }
    \message{new numerator=\newnumerator, pre num=\myprenum,new
    denominator=\newdenominator, pre den=\mypreden^^J}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myr}{(\myprenum/\mypreden)*sqrt(\newnumerator/\newdenominator)}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\c,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at  ({(pow(\b,2) + pow(\c,2) - pow(\a,2))/(2*\c)},{sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c) *(-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))/(2*\c)},0);
    \coordinate (T) at  (\c/2, {\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c)))},0);
    \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/right,T/below}
    {
        \fill (\point) circle (1.8pt);
        \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
    }
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (\myr); 
    \end{scope}
 \draw (T)  -- (C) node[midway,sloped,fill=white] {%
 $\displaystyle\ifnum\mypreden=1
  \myprenum
 \else
  \frac{\myprenum}{\mypreden}
 \fi
 \ifnum\newdenominator=1
  \ifnum\newnumerator=1
  \else
   \cdot\sqrt{\newnumerator}
  \fi
 \else 
  \ifnum\newnumerator=1
   \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\newdenominator}}
  \else
   \cdot\sqrt{\frac{\newnumerator}{\newdenominator}}
  \fi
 \fi\,$cm};
 \end{scope}
 \node[above] at (elli.north){$a=\a,b=\b,c=\c$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think, your answer is not automatically.

Comment: Dunmo. I voted for your answer. But, your code doesn't true in every cases. E.G, triangle with lenght 6, 7, 8.

Comment: Please try with sides 3, 4, 5. It is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: The way that you answered is similar to marmot's answers before :) . I like this very much.

Comment: You can see package xintexpr.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Thanks, that's a good suggestion. (Unfortunately the author quit this site after a fight...) How about removing the other comments?

Comment: If the comment does not affect the site, it should not be deleted.