# Plotting curves within a foreach loop and attributing colors from a colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, foreach, loops

I'm trying to plot curves inside a `\foreach` loop and at the same time define their color through a colormap. The color is given accordingly to a parameter of the curve:`(\T/\Tmax*1000)`, where `\T` is the value of an element of the array `\Tarray` and `\Tmax` is the maximum value of these elements. To do this I used the command `\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor`. The full code is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]

%--->Parameters
\def\Xmin{0}                    
\def\Xmax{10}                   
\def\Tarray{1,2,...,10}
\def\Tmax{10}             

%--->Plot

\begin{axis}
[
    legend pos = north east,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$f$},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    colormap/jet,
    colorT/.style={/utils/exec={\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{#1}},color=mapped color}] %Define the variable colorT that corresponds to the color number in the colormap (from 0 to 1000)
]

\foreach \T in \Tarray
{
    \addplot 
    [
        domain=\Xmin:\Xmax,
        samples=100, 
        colorT=(\T/\Tmax*1000)
    ]
    {x/\T*e^(-x/\T)};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$T=\T$}
}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the code in Texmaker the following error appears:

`! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '(1/10*1000)' as a floating point number, sorry`

It seems that `(\T/\Tmax*1000)` in `colorT` is not being evaluated. If I substitute `(\T/\Tmax*1000)` in the code by a numerical value, for example 1, no error appears, and I get the plot that I desire:

[image]

How can I make the code to evaluate `(\T/\Tmax*1000)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two major changes:

1. The parsing error comes from the number format used by `fpu`. To solve the problem, I use `\PgfmathparseFPU` (which also has been used e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504402/194703).) It locally changes the number format to something that Ti*k*Z can digest.
2. You were also facing an expansion issue. I am using the `\edef\temp` trick that is described in the pgfplots manual in section **8.1 Utility Commands**. If you find this too hacky, you could use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead.

Apart from that I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` and slightly changed the parsing order to address the issue you raised in the comments.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\def\PgfmathparseFPU#1{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}%

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]

%--->Parameters
\def\Xmin{0}                    
\def\Xmax{10}                   
\def\Tarray{1,2,...,10}
\def\Tmax{10}             

%--->Plot

\begin{axis}
[
    legend pos = north east,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$f$},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    colormap/jet,
    colorT/.style={/utils/exec={\PgfmathparseFPU{#1}%
    \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{\pgfmathresult}},color=mapped color}] %Define the variable colorT that corresponds to the color number in the colormap (from 0 to 1000)
]

\foreach \T in \Tarray
{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot 
    [
        domain=\Xmin:\Xmax,
        samples=100, 
        colorT={\T*(1000/\Tmax)}
    ]
    {x/\T*e^(-x/\T)};
    \noexpand\addlegendentryexpanded{$T=\T$}}
    \temp
}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It indeed worked. Thank you! I think I understood the changes. They involve commands that I wasn't currently aware of. But explanations are always welcome!

Comment: One more question: an error "Dimension too large" appears when `\T` or `\Tmax` in `(\T/\Tmax*1000)` is bigger than 16383.99998 (I read that this is TeX’s largest dimension) although the result of the operation is lower than  this value. How can I make the compiler to accept these huge values?

Comment: @ÉlioPereira I added an explanation and made some other minor changes, hoping to solve the `dimension too large error`. Note, however, that I never got these errors. If they persist, please tell me which inputs you are using.

Comment: The error still happens. Try for example to change the definition of the `\Tarray` to `\def\Tarray{10000,20000,...,100000}`. You will get an error of the type "Dimensions too large". Anyway your answer was pretty useful and I may work with different units for `\Tarray` so that lower values are attained.

Comment: @ÉlioPereira This is a limitation of `\foreach`. I do not see any easy way to rectify this other than what you are suggesting.